# ActiveRecord: query all records that no association data

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table `User` and table `Post`. A User can have many posts. Here is the schema:

```
User
  user_id
  user_name
Post
  post_id
  post_content
  user_id
```

I want to have a query that: Gets all user without any post. I can do that with raw sql, but I don't know do we have any ways for ActiveRecord or not. If exist, please tell me how.

I can do this based on Marek Lipka's answer:

```
User.includes(:posts).where(posts: { post_id: nil })
```

The thing now that I don't understand is that the query generated by explain is different from query that prints on console.

Here is query that prints on console:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "users"."id") FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "posts"."id" IS NULL
```

Here is query printing on explain. It's more complicated because the query doesn't select all but selects field-by-field.

```
EXPLAIN for: SELECT "users"."id" AS t0_r0, "users"."email_address" AS t0_r1, "users"."first_name" AS t0_r2, "users"."last_name" AS t0_r3, "users"."full_name" AS t0_r4, "users"."avatar_url" AS t0_r5, "users"."profile_name" AS t0_r6, "users"."profile_base_name" AS t0_r7, "users"."profile_base_name_order" AS t0_r8, "users"."quote" AS t0_r9, "users"."user_register_phrase" AS t0_r10, "users"."total_followers" AS t0_r11, "users"."total_followings" AS t0_r12, "users"."token" AS t0_r13, "users"."jwt_token" AS t0_r14, "users"."active_state" AS t0_r15, "users"."role_id" AS t0_r16, "users"."created_at" AS t0_r17, "users"."updated_at" AS t0_r18, "posts"."id" AS t1_r0, "posts"."user_id" AS t1_r1, "posts"."post_type" AS t1_r2, "posts"."book_id" AS t1_r3, "posts"."title" AS t1_r4, "posts"."content" AS t1_r5, "posts"."total_upvotes" AS t1_r6, "posts"."total_downvotes" AS t1_r7, "posts"."total_views" AS t1_r8, "posts"."total_subscriptions" AS t1_r9, "posts"."accent_search" AS t1_r10, "posts"."created_at" AS t1_r11, "posts"."updated_at" AS t1_r12 FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "posts"."id" IS NULL
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to perform left outer join with specific condition:

```
User.includes(:posts).where(posts: { post_id: nil })
```

Comment: thanks so much. it works. the only thing i don't understand now is query is printed on console is different with query when explain. can you explain for me why ? (I have posted additional information on question, please take a look)